# What is the actual infection rate (per 100,000) of Covid-19 in my area (I'm in the UK)?

Tags: dataset, sample

I think I'm misunderstanding some basic data given by the UK Government.

https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-51768274

On the above page, about three fifths of the way down, there is a table entitled, "Infection rates by local authority: Number of cases per 100,000 over seven days". And the average across all areas is close to 7. So that means that the number of cases of Covid-19 in the UK is 7 (new?) per 100,000 , right?

Whereas [here](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/coronavirus-covid-19-information-for-the-public#number-of-cases) and [here](https://coronavirus.data.gov.uk/#category=regions&map=rate) it basically says the rate is in the hundreds: maybe 200 - 500 ish per 100,000 depending on area. If my maths is correct, 7 is nowhere near 350. But my understanding of the data is probably off. So what am I not understanding about this data?

Comment: You have to read the fine print: "over seven days" is not the same as total numbers.  I haven't studied your links, but that's the sort of thing I would focus on for understanding what the numbers mean.

Comment: Also, you have number per 100,000 for each 'Authority', and many authorities are listed. (That's a fair way to compare seriousness of outbreaks in authorities of different sizes.) To get rate for UK _during this time period,_ you would have to know populations for the various authorities, deduce the number of actual cases per authority and _add_ them. If the authorities taken together include the whole of the UK, then you would have the UK total, and you could get cases per 100,000 in the UK from that.

Comment: So that's on average, 7 per 100,000 *new* cases in 1 week, right? I'm being very hand-wavy with the numbers because I just want a very rough idea for what's going on without calculation exactly. And 400 per 100,000 is the fraction of total number of people who have had Covid-19 divided by the total population. So 300,000 / 68 million =approx. 1/250 = approx 400 / 100,000. Ah, that makes more sense.

Comment: after much confusion have come to the same thing.  you can see this better in the [PHE data](https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/897200/Weekly_COVID19_report_data_w27.xlsx) see sheets titled figure 8 and 9.  one is total cases per 100k since the beginning of the epidemic and the other is is the weekly change

Answer (score 0):

From here:

https://www.ons.gov.uk/peoplepopulationandcommunity/healthandsocialcare/conditionsanddiseases/bulletins/coronaviruscovid19infectionsurveypilot/2july2020

we see that:

"We estimate that an average of 1 in 2,200 (45 in 100,000) individuals within the community population in England had COVID-19 at any given time between 14 June and 27 June 2020."

Assume the ratio of cases between my area and the rest of the UK has been constant for a while.

Estimating the number of new cases of Covid-19 in the UK this is 7 per 100,000 on average. My area has 2 cases per 100,000. So a very rough estimate for the rate of Covid-19 cases in my area is 2/7 x 45 = 13 per 100,000 people in my area have Covid-19. So a good approximation will be:

*between 10 and 30 per 100,000 in my area have Cov-19.*

Comment: Do people agree with this?